# Video Training Courses for Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: video, development, training

I'm a software developer with more than 15 years of experience on Windows platform, focused on C#/.NET/SQL Server stack. Recently I decided to explore Linux and learn a new development technology stack which is completely unrelated to Microsoft. After a bit of (re)search/reading I picked Ubuntu as my starting point.

As I'm really a Pluralsight addict, preferring video courses as a starting point for learning new stuff, I wanted to ask if there are any decent video courses for Linux generally or Ubuntu focused ones?

Basically I'm searching for general explanation of OS structure, a bit of system administration, and maybe some considerations for development on Linux system.

Comment: No video, but a good introduction to UNIX/Linux from Microsoft (to keep things familiar) ;-)  http://www.mu.ac.in/unix.pdf

Comment: Can the downvoter at least put a comment so I know what I did wrong?

Comment: @thom Thanks, I love such docs, with a bit of history and drawing parallels between other OS-es.

Comment: Still don't understand why I got downvoted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of search and peeking I decided to take a Pluralsight course: *CompTIA Linux+* by Veronica Henry.
There are two parts: [Part1](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/comptia-linux-plus-pt1) and [Part2](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/comptia-linux-plus-pt2)
I'm almost done with Part2 and I'm pretty much satisfied with what I saw so far.

Answer (score 1):

You may lose focus if you don't download the video tutorials so that you can watch them locally. YouTube has some good Ubuntu tutorial channels, [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/babarehner) for example. What sets the videos in this channel apart from other YouTube tutorial videos, is that while the videos are not interactive, in order to get the full benefit of the videos you should try out the code and even change it in order to get your own customized output.

If you install the youtube-dl application from the Ubuntu Software Center you can batch download an entire series of video tutorials from YouTube with a single command in the terminal, and using the `-c` flag the download can be resumed in the same place it was stopped if it is paused or interrupted. Youtube-dl also lets you choose the format of the video that you want to download. I recommend selecting the 480p mp4 format if it is available. Less than 480p makes it difficult to read the text on the screen, and YouTube videos usually look OK in 480p.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer, I don't think you should look for an overall video series to teach you everything, as it likely doesn't exist.

However there are few areas that you could look into (search youtube).

To get comfortable with Ubuntu as a dev, you should understand how apt-get works. You can download most things you will need, e.g. "sudo apt-get install python-numpy" installs the python module numpy.

For development environment, pretty much everything other than xcode and visual studio is available. So it's going to be specific to your preferences, e.g. do you want emacs or eclipse. Once again search youtube, and you will be able to install them using apt-get ("sudo apt-get install eclipse emacs23" will install them both).

If you are not familiar with the UNIX directory structure, that's very important and I wouldn't try looking for Ubuntu specific videos as any UNIX or LINUX system works mainly the same. I learnt from a written tutorial so I have no specific videos unfortunately.

Now general linux/ubuntu stuff. There are a few youtube channels I like to watch to keep up to date on distros and can teach you some of the more obscure things you can do with your computer:

Nixie Pixel: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBE-FO9JUOghSysV9gjTeHw
Especially check out the earlier videos

InfinitelyGalatic: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3jSNmKWYA04R47fDcc1ImA

Quidsup: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0A3ldncnGQ1M_RU2Wb4L2A

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the hot-spots I should focus on, as that kind of advice is exactly what I need now!  Regarding the links, I was actually trying to avoid YouTube as a source, as I'm still in the MS-enterprise-app-dev mindset, where one expects to have an ultimate authority providing competent training :)